# How to implement generic interface for null type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I had the following code:

```
public interface IResult
{
    StatusCode Code { get; }
    string Error { get; }
}

public interface IResult<T> : IResult
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Result : IResult
{
    public StatusCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public class Result<T> : IResult<T>
{
    public StatusCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I had two interfaces: `IResult` for results without values(like `void`) and `IResult<T>` for results where a value is needed. But I don't want to support two different types. I would like to merge them into single type. If a result has a value the value will be there and for cases where I do not have any value it will be just `null`.

So it's something like this:
(it covers all cases)

```
public interface IResult<T>
{
    StatusCode Code { get; }
    string Error { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Result<T> : IResult<T>
{
    public StatusCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm struggling with cases where `T` is `empty/null`. How can I define a class for such cases ?
So far I found only one idea:

```
public class Result<NullValue> : IResult<NullValue>
{
    public StatusCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public NullValue Value { get; set; }
}

public class NullValue
{
}
```

I'm looking for any other idea except this one:

```
public class ResultWithNoValue : IResult<T>
{
    public StatusCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public object Value => null;
}
```

It doesn't work cause I have to work with:

```
public interface IBaseResponse< out T>
{
    IResult<T> Data { get; }
}
```

And this code is not compilable:

```
public class ResponseWithNoValue : IBaseResponse<object>
{
    public ResultWithNoValue Data { get; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... `null` isn't a type, it's a "value" (well, abscence of a value. If the value is supposed to be a reference type). So how can there be "cases where T is null"? If you have an undeterminable type (I'm guessing), then what do you expect the logic to be?.

Comment: Why do you need a separate type for `null` value? Why just don't use `default` literal or remain `T Value` unset, with default value (which is `null` for reference types)

Comment: It's for cases where there's no value. Imagine, there's a client which sends a command to server to cancel a job. The server contains a handler which can handle a client request and execute a command. Cancel itself is smth like this:`void Cancel(Guid id){//...}` - no return type it's `void`. But it's possible that the handler may fail or cancel itself throw an exception. The client needs this info. IResult<T> describes it: error and code(like OK, ClientError, ServerError)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I didn't get it. How the type will look like ? I need to put a `T` in "Result<T>". I do not know what to put for cases where I do not care(ot just there's no value).

Comment: @isxaker - So why would `IResult<object>` not work there? Or have a complete separate, untyped `IResult { SatusCode { get; } string Error { get; } }` and then have `IResult<T> : IResult { T Value { get; } }`?

Comment: To extend @Corak's point: "cases where T is null" is logically ungrammatical (as generics are **types**, not values, and `null` is a value), "cases where T is _a nullable type_" does make sense, but doesn't really apply to the posted scenario as you're trying to deal with "no type" situation rather than "no value" situations.

Comment: @Flater I see. I didn't say that I need T which is null. Cause T is a type. I asked what T I should use if there's no Value(value of type T is null\default). Case it can be anything - object, string. int etc. But I needed something more specific

Comment: @isxaker: You decide you only want to have `Result<T>` and not `Result`, but then you also decide you want to not use a `T` when you don't need one. Those are two contradictory statements. Your implementation decision contradicts what you actually want. Contradictions aren't something you should try to overcome, it's a matter of not making contradictions in the first place.

Comment: @isxaker - Why do you need "something more specific"? It sounds like it's quite the opposite. You need something more _generic_. `object` has exactly enough properties to communicate a `null`. Anything else would be _too specific_.

Comment: @Flater I completely agree with you

Comment: @Corak I meant something like System.DBNull type. It's more specific I think and the sense is clear from that type name

Comment: Well, noone is stopping you from creating your own `public sealed class MyNull { public static readonly MyNull Value = new MyNull(); private MyNull() { } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you don't want to have two types, but you've not explained *why*. That makes it very hard to understand the problem you're actually trying to solve.

As the question is currently phrased, there's no valid justification for wanting to merge these types into one. They are not the same. One has a result, the other does not.
There is some overlap between them, but that's not an argument for removing one of the types; it's an argument for having them share/reuse some common logic.

In essence, your argument is the same as saying:

> *I don't like having a base class and a derived class, so I'm just going to make the derived class and not use some of the properties when I don't need them.*

Is it technically possible? Sure. Is it a good idea? Nope. It flies in the face of static typing, OOP principles, and general clean coding practices.

By merging the two result types, you omit the no-value result type, leading to the exact problem you're faced with: the inability to gracefully implement a no-value result.

---

What I suspect you may have glossed over is that `Result<T>` can inherit from `Result` *as well as* implement the `IResult<T>` interface:

```
// other interfaces/classes are unchanged

public class Result<T> : Result, IResult<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to **reuse** some of the `Result` logic when handling `Result<T>` objects, in cases where you don't need to interact with a potential return value.

Note that this mirrors similar use cases, e.g. the `Task` and `Task<T>` return types in async code. The types are different because they are expected to be handled differently. However, any `Task<T>` can be treated exactly like any other `Task`, since `Task<T> : Task`.

---

> If a result has a value the value will be there and for cases where I do not have any value it will be just null.

That's just asking for null reference exceptions. There are valid cases to be made for `null`, but I strongly advise against creating even more cause to write `null` checks than is necessary.

By relying on the static typing of your no-value result type, you effectively ensure that you don't need null checks.

Since the fact whether a given method returns a no-value result or a value result is hardcoded in the method body anyway, there's nothing lost from having the method's return type actually reflect that as well.

This is a matter of making it clear to your consumer what they can expect from your method. By merging your result types, you make it unclear and therefore needlessly obfuscate your interface.

---

Note also that I don't quite see the need to have the `IResult`/`IResult<T>` interfaces here as you're dealing with what are essentially value objects, but since your question is light on context there may be ulterior reasons to have the interfaces which are simply not apparent from this question.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. I myself have implemented a `Result/Result<T>` pair much like the OP in the past, and your answer cleared any doubt the question have raised about choosing to implement them as a pair. +1 for that.

Comment: This is exactly my problem - "the inability to gracefully implement a no-value result"
On the one hand it's two different types, on the other hand this inability

Comment: @isxaker: My point is that it is a problem of your own making. You _had_ a good way to deal with it (the  `IResult`/`Result` types), and then you decided to do away with them - without any concrete justification as to why you've come to that decision. It is that decision to do away with them that is the problem. The solution is to not do away with them.

Comment: @isxaker _"On the one hand it's two different types"_ But **why is that a problem?** You clearly seem to think it is, but you don't justify that position. The existence of these two classes isn't a problem, it's a solution that provides the ability to return a value in some cases and not in others, which is exactly what you're looking for. Without explaining your reasoning why you think it's a problem, it's impossible to explore how you came to the conclusion that you did and where the mistake was made.

Comment: "But why is that a problem" I have one entry point and do not want to use casting(even safe casting like `is`). like `var respose = server.sendRequest(request); responce.EnsureSuccess(); //etc`. I think it would be easier to use one branch of code without if else, without having different extensions for both types. But I think It''s worth it. I think I'll go back to two types instead one.

Comment: @isxaker: You shouldn't be casting to begin with. Why do you have only one entry point, when you clearly have at least two different call stacks (i.e. at least one where there is a value result, and at least one where there is a no-value result). I'm beginning to suspect that you're building your system in the wrong order and are trying to force your backend to conform to a predetermined API that just cannot accommodate all of the backend's needed features. This question is an XY problem, and you really need to elaborate on the X to get an answer to your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

> And this code is not compilable:
>
> ```
> public class ResponseWithNoValue : IBaseResponse<object>
> {
>     public ResultWithNoValue Data { get; }
> }
> ```

No, and nor is using any other implementation class for `Data`; it can only be `IResult<object>`:

```
public class ResponseWithNoValue : IBaseResponse<object>
{
    public IResult<object> Data { get; }
}
```

That approach might suit your needs.

When you create an instance of `Result<object>` then just don't set a `Value`. The interface is get-only anyway, so it would be immutably null:

```
public class ResponseWithNoValue : IBaseResponse<object>
{
    public IResult<object> Data { get; }
    public ResponseWithNoValue(StatusCode code, string Error)
    {
        Data = new Result<object> { Code = code, Error = error };
    }
}

var response = new ResponseWithNoValue(SomeCode, "SomeError");
var val = response.Data.Value; // null
response.Data.Value = new object(); // Compilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with null values is the fact that value types can't be null.
You can work around that by using `default` instead of `null` (and simply not initialize the `Value` property if the result is a failed result).

That being said, I would suggest making your class immutable:

```
public class Result<T> : IResult<T>
{
    public Result(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public Result(StatusCode code, string error)
    {
        Code = code;
        Error = error;
    }

    public StatusCode Code { get; }
    public string Error { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

Even better - use a private constructor and static `Success/Fail` methods to create instances of the `Result<T>` class:

```
public interface IResult<T>
{
    StatusCode Code { get; }
    string Error { get; }
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Result<T> : IResult<T>
{

    public static Result<T> Success(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T>(null, "", value);
    }

    public static Result<T> Fail(StatusCode code, string Error)
    {
        return new Result<T>(code, error, default);
    }

    private Result(StatusCode code, string error, T value)
    {
        Code = code;
        Error = error;
        Value = value;
    }

    public StatusCode Code { get; }
    public string Error { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = Result<int>.Success(5);

var result = Result<SomeType>.Fail(new StatusCode(1), "Failed to do something");
```

This makes it very easy to understand if the result was a success or fail by reading the calling code.

Comment: `var result = Result<string>.Fail(new StatusCode(1), "Failed to do something");` this's confusing me why `string`. In fact it can be any type

Comment: @isxaker changed to `Result<SomeType>` for more clarity.